# Python combining html and xml files into a single dictionary

Tags: python, html, xml, dictionary

I'm trying to combine html files (text) and xml files (metadata) into a single flat dictionary which I'll write as a Json. The files are contained in the same folder and have following name structure:

- abcde.html
- abcde.html.xml

Here's my simplified code, my issue is that I had to separate the xml meta-data writing into

```
        ### Create a list of dict with one dict per file, first write file content then meta-data

        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk("."):
            for fname in files:

                docname, extension = os.path.splitext(fname)

                filename = os.path.join(path,fname)

                file_dict = {}
    
                if extension == ".html":
                    file_dict['type'] = 'circulaire'
                    file_dict['filename'] = fname

                    html_dict = parse_html_to_dict(filename)
                    file_dict.update(html_dict)
                    list_of_dict.append(file_dict)
                
                #elif extension == ".xml":
                #   if not any(d['filename'] == docname for d in list_of_dict):
                #       print("Well Well Well, there's no html file in the list yet !")
                #       continue
                #   else:
                #       index = next((i for i, element in enumerate(list_of_dict) if element['filename'] == docname), None) 
                #       metadata_dict = extract_metadata_xml(filename)
                #       list_of_dict[index].update(metadata_dict)

                else: continue

        json.dump(list_of_dict, outfile, indent=3)

        outfile.close()

############# Extract Metadata from XML FILES #############
import xmltodict

def extract_metadata_xml(filename):
    """ Returns xml file to dict """
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as xml_file:
        temp_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
        metadata_dict = temp_dict.get('doc', {}).get('fields', {})
    xml_file.close()

    return metadata_dict
```

Normally, I would add an elif condition (now commented) below the if loop for html files, which checks for xml and updates the corresponding dictionary (bool condition that filenames are identical) with the metadata, thus sequentially.

But, unfortunately it seems that for most files, the list of dict isn't fully up to date, or at least I can't find a match for 40% of my filenames.

The work-around I use seems a little silly to me, I wrote a second loop with os.walk after the first one which is used exclusively for html files, my second loop then checks for xml extensions and appends the list_of_dict, which is fully up to date and I get 100% of my html filenames matched with xml metadata.

Can I introduce some forced timing to make sure my html is done writing before I start to match any xml filename, is it possible that both if/elif loops are executed in parallel for different files?

Or else what is in terms of processing the best way to have all my html files processed before my xml files (just ordering my list of files by type before proceeding with my if/elif loops?)

I'm quite new to this forum, so please let me know if I can improve my question writing style, be mindful though that I'm trying my best ;).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the naming convention is as you described, you should be able to get the corresponding xml file for each html file you encounter by `xml_filename = os.path.join(path, fname+'.xml')`. Open and process it after the html file and store it to the dict within the same loop, no need to loop over everything twice.

Comment: NB: `else: continue` at the end of a loop does literally nothing, so better just remove it.

Comment: Thanks, @fsimonjetz, (filename) and (fname + '.xml') are the same thing, so this is the methodology I was trying to apply, still in the same loop it works for 60% of my files but not for the rest of them. For sake of completeness I now added the code for my metadata extraction function... please lmk if you see an issue there? Thanks for your time!

Comment: unrelated question, but I'm using the get method to extract the value from my nested dict. But I'd actually prefer to raise an exception in case that key has no value attached, should I therefor use square bracket notation with try/except statements? Something more like:  `try: metadata_dict = temp_dict['doc']['fields']`followed by an except statement to catch a KeyError exception?

Comment: The most pythonic way to handle possibly missing keys is to check whether the key exists with `if key in temp_dict:` and then handle both cases accordingly. `try/except` is really only for cases where you have no control over the inputs, like catching user input. But all of that shouldn't be necessary in your case if you follow the strategy I outlined in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it is now you check all files and handle them differently, depending on whether they are html or xml, hoping that the corresponding html for each xml you encounter has already been processed – but that's not guaranteed, which I suspect to be the cause of the issues.

Instead, you should only look for html files and retrieve the corresponding xml right away:

```
if extension == ".html":
    file_dict['type'] = 'circulaire'
    file_dict['filename'] = fname
    html_dict = parse_html_to_dict(filename)
    file_dict.update(html_dict)
    
    # process the corresponding xml file

    # this file should always exist, according to your description of the file structure
    xml_filename = os.path.join(path, fname+'.xml')

    # extract the meta data
    metadata_dict = extract_metadata_xml(xml_filename)

    # put it in the file dict we still have
    file_dict.update(metadata_dict)

    # and finally store it
    list_of_dict.append(file_dict)
```

Alternatively, though less efficiently, you could also iterate over the *sorted* file list - `for fname in sorted(files):` - and proceed as you did, as this would also result in the html files preceding the corresponding xml files.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give this a try on Monday and let you know if that worked, but I’m sure it will. As to why the processing would not happen sequentially, can you elaborate a little? Just tryin to understand the basic principle here, if the files aren’t cycled through sequentially but in parallel when I separate xml & html file handling un if/else statements?

Comment: Sure. The problem ultimately is that the `os` module lists files in (more or less) arbitrary order. So you might get `abcde.html.xml` *before* `abcde.html`. But if you only look for the \*.html files and build the path to the corresponding \*.xml file manually, the html is guaranteed to be done processing when you add the content of the xml.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this! It did work as expected with your advice!